# Bounded component of the complement of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$. Suppose these sets are disjoint. It seems correct that if the complement of their union has a bounded component $C$, and $\overline{C}\cap A_1\not=\emptyset$, then $C$ must be a bounded component of $A_1$. Is this correct? How to prove it?

Comment: Are you sure about "then $C$ must be the bounded component of $A_1$"? It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I do not see how the complement of their union could ever have a bounded component. This is because each $A_1,A_2$ are closed and bounded, and so there must be disjoint balls $B_1,B_2$ such that $A_1\subseteq B_1$ and $A_2\subseteq B_2.$ (Why?) The complement of $B_1\cup B_2$ must be unbounded and is also connected (Why?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It's not true as you can show in this picture. For example the complement of union has two bounded component and the closure of the ''exterior ring to $A_2$'' satisfyng that your closure intercept $A_1$ and are not a component of $A_1$.

Comment: +1. Even if we interpret "$the$ bounded component of $A_1$" to mean that $A_1$ has exactly one bounded component.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet. You are right. I corrected the question.